# How to specify "all" or "don't care" in a DVWP query string parameter value

Tags: data-view-web-part

If I specify multiple parameters for a DVWP, I seem to have to always provide a value in the query string or I get nothing. For example,

```
 [url]?filter=waldo&category=book
```

How would I specify "everything from waldo and not limited to books" *presuming* that I must provide the 'category' parameter in the URL (which seems to be true for this web part)? One would presume something like * should work but it doesn't.

There is a field for "default value" but the question still applies: how to specify any, or all, or don't care.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a compound filter condition, something like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[@Category = $Category or $Category = '*']"/>
```

where

$Category is the parameter you've set up for the category Query String value

This way, if you pass an asterisk '*' for category, you'll get all categories.

Answer (score 0):

Michael,

```
DefaultValue="*"
```

...should work.

But the question comes in with how that's passed to the query.

Can you post the **SharePoint:SoapDataSource** tag here for troubleshooting?

Comment: Will look for SoapDataSource, but for now with 'fair' and 'appt' specified within the DVWP,
.../ReviewResume5.aspx?fair=something&appt=student
returns a row
.../ReviewResume5.aspx?fair='*'&appt='*'
and
.../ReviewResume5.aspx?fair="*"&appt="*"
return nothing.

Comment: The '*' will only work as a string value, not in any sort of wildcard way.